# No module named cmake

Tags: python-3.x, cmake

When I run the command

```
cmake --version
```

It gives me the version. 
But when I run

```
import cmake
```

It gives the error cmake module not present.

I am stuck and not getting how to resolve it

Answer (score 5):

You are talking about two different things:

1. When running `cmake --version`, you are calling the command line program [CMake](https://cmake.org/)
2. When using `import cmake` in a Python program (or interactive session) you are using the [cmake Python module](https://pypi.org/project/cmake/).

You are missing the second one. You can install it, e.g. by calling

```
pip install cmake
```

Answer (score 0):

For me on MacOSX when I initially install `CMake` by `pip`, it goes to the similar behaviour.

It was solved by uninstalling `CMake` by `pip`, and installing `CMake` first by `brew` before installing by `pip`, and before it installing `brew` itself, by running in terminal commands from [How to run CMake in Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825564/how-to-run-cmake-in-mac/59825656#59825656) answer.

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt install qdldl either and found the cmake module was not found error

after a while i noticed that the virtual environment was no active, try activating your virtual environment and then installing cmake in that directory. after that ive opened jupyter labs and tried installing qdldl and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).