# How to run CMake in Mac?

Tags: macos, cmake

I'm following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vJJMU2gMn4
but when I tried to run cmake using the command "cmake ." on Mac (which is around 2:02 in video), [the results on my Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoO3D.png) show that the command cmake is not found. May I ask some help to run cmake on Mac, please?

Comment: You need to **install** CMake first. Do you have Homebrew installed? You can install with Homebrew or download from [here](https://cmake.org/download/).

Comment: Also, Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 37):

If you have homebrew, just type:

`brew install cmake`

Answer (score 10):

Install brew

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

And then cmake

```
brew install cmake
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It worked!! :D

Comment: Install brew
`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`