# Pip installs failing because cmake not found

Tags: cmake, python-3.10

Attempting to `pip3 install pyportfolioopt`, the build fails with

```
...ERROR: Failed building wheel for osqp
Failed to build osqp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for osqp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

...in the traceback, I can see that the problem is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/cmake", line 5, in <module>
          from cmake import cmake
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
```

So `pip3 install cmake`; `pip3 list | grep cmake`: `cmake  3.24.0` ...try again, but same error.

OSX 12.5 (Monterey) - M1 Chip
Python 3.10.6

Edit:
Pleas note that the Python `cmake` module is distinct from the `cmake` build tool.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, when I looked in the contents of `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/cmake` there was a `from cmake import cmake` line (but no actual file called `cmake.py`).  So I tried to pip install again:
`pip3 install cmake`, which returned the comment: `Requirement already satisfied: cmake in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (3.24.0)` ...which I don't totally understand as `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10` is a binary file, not a directory, but this puzzlement led me to try: `pip3 uninstall cmake`, and then retry installing the original library: `pip3 install pyportfolioopt`.  Strangely enough, this worked.

So, in short: the way to solve the `no module named cmake` bug was to uninstall cmake.... go figure.

Would love any additional insight that anyone can provide though.

Comment: this is really really f**king weired, uninstall cmake even can work.....

Comment: you just saved my evening, thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-build/cmake-python-distributions/issues/324

Answer (score 1):

For me on MacOSX it was solved by installing CMake first by brew, and before it installing brew itself, by running in terminal commands from [How to run CMake in Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825564/how-to-run-cmake-in-mac/59825656#59825656) answer.