# error while install dlib on cmd, could not build wheels for dlib

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, cmake, pip, dlib

im getting this error while trying o install dlib on cmd
i already install cmake version 3.26.1
visual studio
n python version is 3.10

pip install dlib

and the results

```
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.24.1.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\shiri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
          return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
        File "C:\Users\shiri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
          exec(code, run_globals)
        File "C:\Users\shiri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\cmake.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'

      ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

i dont know what to do, please help:"

Comment: "_CMake must be installed to build dlib_" ... have you installed CMake? https://cmake.org/download/

Comment: yes, n i dont know why it says i dont

Comment: Did you restart your shell to get it to pick up changes to your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'` - Have you **searched** for that error message? E.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58992376/3440745) suggests that you need to install **Python module** named "cmake".

Comment: yes i already install cmake

Comment: What do you mean by "install cmake"? Have you installed the **program** or the **Python package** (via `pip`)?

Answer (score 2):

> ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

You can do these commands in terminal:

```
pip install cmake
```

Then reinstall `dlib`.

You said you have installed the cmake package, you can also check whether you have chosen the correct Python interpreter.

Comment: i have alredy installed cmake Version: 3.26.3 and the eror when installing dlib is still going

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade pip and setuptools: Before attempting to install dlib again, you can upgrade pip and setuptools to their latest versions using the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

Retry installing dlib: Now, you can try installing dlib again using pip:

```
pip install dlib
```

Answer (score 0):

For those running on a linux this helped me.
Install the build-essential package, which includes the gcc and g++ compilers and make, along with cmake.

`yum install -y gcc-c++ make cmake`

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the `dlib-whl` file. For example, if you're using python 3.11 then you will download `dlib-whl` file for this specific python version. After downloading just move into the directory where you saved the `dlib-whl` file and then run
 `py -m pip install dlib-whl-file-name` (Replace dlib-whl-file-name with actual filename).
You can also follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zeb902f98s

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Windows system, to install **dlib**, you need to have **C++** installed.

"*You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.*"

Answer (score 0):

Running on Conda environment worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Let me say straightforward...
if ur doing ai project like face recognition or something like that... dlib plays a crucial role.
So, follow my steps to solve the error..

Step1 -- Install CMake.
Download and install CMake from the official website. Or use pip install cmake.

Step2 -- Install Visual Studio Build Tools.
dlib requires a C++ compiler, and on Windows, you can use the Visual Studio Build Tools. You can download and install them from the official website.
During installation, make sure to select the "Desktop development with C++" workload.

Step3 -- Install Boost.
dlib depends on the Boost C++ libraries. You can manually install Boost by following these steps:

Download the Boost library from the official website: Boost C++ Libraries.
Extract the Boost archive to a location on your machine.
Open a Command Prompt and navigate to the Boost directory.
Run the following command to build Boost:
bootstrap.bat
then run:
b2
Thats it....

now intall dlib (try pip3 instead of pip).